# How to get the pathname in JS after the /?

Tags: javascript

If the current url is: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"

What's a good way to just get: "questions/ask" ?

Comment: `window.location.pathname`

Comment: @RGraham I want the pathname AFTER the /

Comment: just remove it from string. (.substr(1);)

Comment: @Fataoulas Did you really try to find how yourself?

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
window.location.pathname.substring(1)
```

Comment: This gets the starting /. i want evertyhing after this

Comment: @Fataoulas You said you wanted the string without the domain or protocol. `/` is not part of the domain, it *is* part of the path.

Comment: just remove it from string. (.substr(1);)

Answer (score 0):

You would use `window.location.pathname`

```
console.log(window.location.pathname.substring(1));
```

This would output everything after the first `/`